# How to import a custom class which is within its own folder?

Tags: ios, swift

Salutations,

So I was looking around the web and none of the answers really gave me what I need, I am still quite a novice to swift and as such I am used to java's rather straightforward import rules. I digress.

So my file structure is as follows: 
I have my project folder, in it i have a models folder which contains a file called CityData.swift. Outside of this folder all of my other view controllers sit within the projectFolder as is standard for Xcode's new project layout.

My issue is that I want to create an array of type CityData as follows:

```
var data:[CityData] = [CityData(cityName:"Moscow", cityHighLight:"Capital of Russia")].
```

However, I am getting an error saying use of undeclared type. How can I declare this type, and also am I calling the constructor correctly inside of my array. As far as I am aware, init() is how you make a constructor, and swift does not have the concept of "new".

Edit: figured it out, no need for imports, just accidentally capitalized my c is cityData. Now I am getting a new error though `cannot use instance member 'cityData' within properly initalizer; property initializer run before self is available.`

What does this mean, and how would I call my constructor within the cityData array then?

Edit 2: Code sample:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutler wear var cityPicker :UIPickerView!; 
    var data = [cityData]();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         data = [cityData(cityName: "Moscow", cityHighLight:"Russian Capital")
    }
```

And for how the cityData class looks like:

```
cityData {
   var cityName:String;
   var cityHighLight:String;

   init(cityName:String, cityHighLight:String) {
      self.cityName = cityName;
      self.cityHighLight = cityHighLight;
   }

   //getter methods below since swifts get/set within a variable make 0 sense.

}
```

Edit: 3

VC:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{


    var lat:Double = 0.0;
    var long:Double = 0.0;

    @IBOutlet weak var cityPicker: UIPickerView!;
    @IBOutlet weak var dataFromPicker: UILabel!;


    var data = [cityData]();
    var cityData:[String] = ["Waycross", "Plains", "Athens", "Milledgeville", "Wrightsville"];
    var cityHighlights:[String] = ["Alligators", "Peanuts", "Heaven on Earth", "Mental Hospital", "Home of Herschel"];



    //number of columns
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    //number of rows
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return cityData.count;
    }

    //title for row
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        dataFromPicker.text = cityHighlights[row];
        return cityData[row];

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        data = [
            cityData(cityName:"Moscow", cityHighLight:"Russians", cityLat: 200.0, cityLong:200.0)
        ];


        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataFromPicker.textAlignment = .center;
        self.cityPicker.dataSource = self;
        self.cityPicker.delegate = self;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

cityData.swift:

import Foundation

```
class cityData {
    var cityName:String;
    var cityHighLight:String;
    var cityLat:Double;
    var cityLong:Double;

    init(cityName: String, cityHighLight:String, cityLat:Double, cityLong:Double) {
        self.cityName = cityName;
        self.cityHighLight = cityHighLight;
        self.cityLat = cityLat;
        self.cityLong = cityLong;
    }
}
```

Comment: By convention, your class should start with a capital letter. Have you read the section on initializers in the Swift Book from Apple? (In fact read the whole book). Please edit your question to show the Initializer.

Comment: I have not had the chance to yet. I am following along with RayWenderlich and I was trying to do something similar to his tableview example, only with pickerviews. However, If I declare my cityData array outside of viewDidLoad it throws the error i mentioned above, if within viewdidload then it throws cannot call value of non-function type [String]. Eh..it is these minor errors that truly make no sense.

Comment: Can you show us a little more of your code, so we can see how you're setting up your ViewController?

Comment: Sure thing, i put up a snippet of it. I am trying to rework or base my idea of of this thing here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial and his sample code lacks this issue 100%. Is it because I have that extra models folder where I keep my cityData? I doubt it, but at this point all I can say is that Java makes infinitely more sense.

Comment: @matt I am showing the part in question, the rest should not matter. Maybe you can idk, can stop living up to the SO stereotype of people with what appears to be a superiority complex.

Comment: My apologies, I just have a massive immediate lashing out response to most people on SO as I know that it can be, and is, a hostile place.

Comment: "figured it out, no need for imports, just accidentally capitalized my c is cityData" That is the answer I gave. Please do not "bait and switch" by changing your question completely. I correctly answered the question you originally asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134923/discussion-between-somestudent-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

> And for how the cityData class looks like

The problem is that `cityData` and `CityData` are two different names. Your class needs to be called `CityData`, and it needs to be properly declared.